# discord.js Get all guilds discord bot joined in

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to do a bot command with total guilds bot joined in (code: `client.guilds.size`) but it's returns me `undefined`, how do i can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `client.guilds.cache.size`
I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing: `client.guilds.cache.size`